# Upgrade Angular 2 with SystemJS to Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-cli, upgrade, systemjs

I have to update a Angular 2 app with SystemJS to the latest version of Angular, currently Angular 7. It also lacks the Angular CLI and I would like to add it to the project, so there are two big changes.

I have read this:
https://update.angular.io/
But there's nothing about SystemJS in there.

Also read this, but it's only about SystemJS: [Move project from SystemJS to Angular CLI / Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738595/move-project-from-systemjs-to-angular-cli-webpack)

So, which is the best order to accomplish this task? Start a Angular7 project from scratch with AngularCLI and paste files and fix things? Go step by step upgrading angular and then change SystemJS to AngularCLI? First change SystemJS to AngularCLI and then upgrade Angular version?

Thank you.

Comment: [https://update.angular.io/](https://update.angular.io/)

Comment: Already seen that. It doesn't help at all with SystemJS.

Comment: SystemJS is just a way to serve your files and map them between your client and your server. Angular-CLI takes care of this taks with the bundling.
Just add Angular-CLI, and follow the steps to upgrade. 

This is why you should have upgraded a long time ago progressively and not from v2 to v7 : your experience will be painful.

Answer (score 1):

From angular 2 to angular 7, things change a lot. I think the best way should be:

- Install `angular-cli`, and learn the command `ng` ;
- Create a default project with `ng new` and with other parameters like `--styles scss` (if you use scss), `--routing true` (if you use routing), and ther parameters, depends on what your old project use.
- Compair the project you created, and your old project, directory structure changed a lot, you should know which folder is for source code, which folder is for unit test, and which folder is for e2e test;
- Delete all the source code (*.ts, *.html, *.scss or *.css) in the `src/app` folder of the project created by `ng` command;
- Copy the code of your old project to the correspond folder of your new project;
- Install the npm packages of your old projects;
- Try build your projects with `ng build`, and fix any erros;
- Then build your project with `ng build --prod`, and fix any errors again;
- If you can build your project, try `ng serve` to serve it, and navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:4200` with your browser, see what happens.

Upgrade from angular 2 to angular 7 may be a big challenge, and good luck!

Comment: Thank you! So create a new project with angular CLI and start copying the old project in the new structure and fixing bugs. :)